# member function chosen over the function with the same name in the member function definition

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Assume I have a function:

```
template<class T>
void save(aType var1, aType var2, T varT) // var1, var2 - do not matter
  {
  // ...
  }
```

Now I have the class, which defines this function for itself, as the member function

```
class A {
  public:
  ....
  void save(aType var1, aType var2); // the same as before; only 2 arguments
};
```

Here is the implementation of the member-function class:

```
// A.cpp
#include "save.h"
#include "A.h"
void A::save(aType var1, aType var2){

  save(var1,var2,one-of-the-members); // here we try to call templated function
}
```

As a result, compiler says no matching function for call to A::save(var1,var2,var3) candidate is: A::save(var1,var2); That is compiler tries to use the member-function of class A (in the implementation of this function)- with 2 arguments, but looks like it does not see templated version for 3 arguments. 
How to make that templated version win over the member-function?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all previous answers. The methods suggested still do not help. Well, not actually. Here are some more details/questions:

In addition to templated version:

```
template<class T>
void save(aType var1, aType var2, T varT) // var1, var2 - do not matter
{
// ...
}
```

i also overloaded the function for some more specific types, so I also have:

```
void save(aType var1, aType var2, Type1 varT);
void save(aType var1, aType var2, Type2 varT);
void save(aType var1, aType var2, Type3 varT);
...
```

The methods suggested (e.g. using :: to bring global scope) help if I comment the templated definition, otherwise there are some unrelated compiler errors. So my next question is: is it possible to overload the function and have its templated version? They seem to be competing.

I also thought about doing run-type identification of the types (of the variable varT):

```
if(typeid(varT).name()==type_name_1){  ... }
else if(typeid(varT).name()==type_name_2){ ... }
...
```

but I think this will be inefficient, so this is not good approach. So what i want to do it to use templated version for basic types (int, double, etc.)- so not to overload for each type explicitly - and use my own functions to deal with more complex types. Is is possible to do this efficiently? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @phresnel: it should not matter, this is typical name hiding.

Comment: You are asking a different question now, post the errors you get with the templates versions.

Comment: @Matthieu: My comment was on his edit, where he states that explicit qualification does not help. (at)user938720: Would you mind posting a complete testcase?

Comment: i use gcc-4.6.0 compiler. About the testcase: now i walked around this problem with the templates by explicitly overloading the save function for some basic types, but the error message was not relevant to the problem - was saying something about conversion from const T to T& in overloading << operator (where T is one of my types) - so that message was not any useful.

Answer (score 3):

Either explicitly qualify the call, or bring it into scope with a using declaration.

Explicit qualification:

```
::save(var1,var2,one-of-the-members);
```

Using declaration:

```
using ::save;
```

Comment: what do you mean by explicitly qualifying the call? do you mean put <> in front of the called template function? - I tried that and this does not help. and how can I bring the scope of the templated function-non-member to be chosen inside the definition of the function-member?

Answer (score 0):

```
::save(var1,var2,one-of-the-members);
```

The :: qualifier will match a free function, rather than a member function.  BTW: your issue has nothing to do with templates.  It's a member function / free function issue.